# What is this MVC feature called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recall a feature in MVC that lets you influences the source object with which to derive parameter values for a given method.

```
public ActionResult Foo([SomethingHere] int parameter)
{
    // do something with parameter

    return View();
}
```

The bracketed "[SomethingHere]" would contain a member called "parameter" that MVC would then try to get an int from. I forget what this feature is called, and my Google fu is apparently weak. What is this called?

Comment: You mean model binding?

Comment: @L-Three I've known about model binding, though moreso in the model to view context. So, you were right, objectively, but the subset of the functionality I was looking for was contained in ParameterBinding, as indicated by CodeCaster. I was trying to evaluate whether or not I should use it somewhere and it appears to be rather Web API specific and not MVC. I misspoke on that part, admittedly, out of simply trying to figure out what I was trying to remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `[Thing]` is called an attribute. Attributes in and of themselves do nothing, they merely provide metadata.

Using attributes, you can instruct MVC to handle certain things different from their defaults.

In this case, you're overriding the default model binder behavior.

See for "documentation" the following: [ASP.NET MVC Preview 5 and Form Posting Scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios). Here the parameter attribute `[Bind]` is explained amongst others.

MSDN has even less information: [BindAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), [ModelBinderAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about custom model binders?

```
public class HomeCustomDataBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(
        ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Various things.
    }
}

public ActionResult Index(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(HomeCustomBinder))] HomePageModels home)
{
    // Various things.
}
```

See [ASP.NET MVC Custom Model Binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) for an extended example.